# How to Retrofit call this API GET method

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I passing TranID from using GET method. I have a problem for API call , please give some example API calls. http://testing.ppms.co.in/Redipae/Payout/Approvemercsmspwalink?TranID=20

{
"result": true,
"newurl": "/Redipae/Payout/mercpushsmslink"
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrofit client defined below

```
public class API {
  public static Retrofit getClient() {
        return new Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).baseUrl(" http://testing.ppms.co.in/").client(new OkHttpClient.Builder().connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS).writeTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS).readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
    }
}
```

You need an interface for the API

```
public interface RequestServer {
    @GET("Redipae/Payout/Approvemercsmspwalink")
    Call<ResponseBody> getResponse(@Query("TranID") int transId);
}
```

Finally, call it like this

```
        RequestServer requestServer = API .getClient().create(RequestServer.class);
        requestServer.getResponse(20).enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ResponseBody> call, @NonNull Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                // do something with the data here
            }   

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ResponseBody> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                // check the error and inform the user about it
            }
        });
```